# AppDelegate issues

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I'm working on my first project on Swift. I'm new to iOS itself.

I create various screens like register, sign in etc. using storyboard.
The Register screen is linked from the Sign In screen. But the app crashes as soon as I tap on 'Register' link in the Sign In screen.

I haven't defined anything in the default view controller. However, I've created the register user view controller where I've defined App Delegate. 
Below is my code for Register user view controller:

```
class RegisterUserViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var FFName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FAge: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FGender: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FLocation: UITextField!


    @IBAction func registerUser(sender: UIButton) {
        //define an app delegate
        //define a managed context
        //define an entity description
        //perform entity operation like add, delete, search
        //save the context

        var appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var newUsr = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObjectContext

        newUsr.setValue("myusername", forKey: "username")
        newUsr.setValue(FFName, forKey: "fullname")
        newUsr.setValue(FEmail.text, forKey: "email")
        newUsr.setValue(FPassword.text, forKey: "password")
        newUsr.setValue(FAge, forKey: "age")
        newUsr.setValue(FGender, forKey: "gender")
        newUsr.setValue(FLocation, forKey: "location")

        context.save(nil)
        println(FFName.text)
        println(FEmail.text)
    }
```

Could you please suggest if this is the right way to work with App Delegates or do I need to define anything in AppDelegate.swift?

Appreciate any information.

Thanks

Comment: what error message you got?

Comment: what does crash log tells?

Comment: Personally I don't abuse the app delegate ever, even for the core data access. App delegate is there for handling application level events and it should stay that way. In your case, for core data, I use custom object to do the work. You can find brief information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Comment: Set a breakpoint - to what line do you get? ;)

Comment: @Desdenova, could you please explain how you can do it with a custom object? I'm sorry if I sound really silly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NOTE: GENERAL ADVICE

You are referencing the AppDelegate from the ViewController to get the context.

This works but creates a dependency of the VC to the appDelegate... not the nicest thing :D

two alternatives:
- give the view controller a var ctx and pass it to it from the appDelegate
- make a DataStoreManager class that has the CD stack. (That moves this code out of the appDelegate which is ideal IMHO - setting up a CD stack doesn't really belong into a controller)

in the end though: it ALSO comes down to personal preference

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the register button and agin add the register button.. may be previously declare action is there and after that you have changes the function name so this kind of crash accrued.

**Solutions**

- Right click on button and see the already bind action method if there is unnecessary method than remove it.
- Remove button and again add new button and bind action method